# In App purchase returns 0 products, testing on Simulator, IAP in Ready to submit status

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have setup IAP methods and `SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()` returns true. But still when `productsRequest.start()` is executed I get no result at all. `func productsRequest(_ request:, didReceive response:)` never responds.

Here is the piece of code:

```
var productsRequest = SKProductsRequest()

private func requestProductsWithProductIdentifiers() {
        
        let productIdentifiers = Set(arrayLiteral: "com.myapp.iap1")
        
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
            productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)
            productsRequest.delegate = self;
            productsRequest.start()
        } else {
            print("Can't make purchases")
        }
        
    }

func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    dump(response)
    let productsFromResponse = response.products
        
    for product in productsFromResponse {
            products[product.productIdentifier] = product
    }
}
```

• Am I doing it right?
• Does it work when run in Simulator **(iOS 14,*)**?
• In-App-Purchase on App Store is in "Ready to submit" status. Does it have to be approved before I get any response?

**Update: This problem is solved but now I see even though my phone connects to the App Store APIs, it returns 0 products. My product ID is correctly being used in the app.**

Comment: You should test it on the iOS device. Because the iOS simulator can’t connect to App Store servers.

Comment: @Mannopson Yeah! Right. Thanks a lot!